# What plans do the Biden-Harris administration have for helping and contributing to the African-American Community?

Tags: united-states, joe-biden, social-policy, kamala-harris

Joe Biden and Kamala Harris have been elected as President and Vice President by citizens of the United States of America and have said they have plans to help the African-American community. I am interested and would like to know their plans in detail. So what are they planning to do apart from:

> “rooting out systemic racism from our laws, our policies, our institutions, and our hearts,

<sub>[Excerpt from ABC news](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/biden-releases-plan-focused-african-american-community-racial/story?id=70497573)</sub>

Doing that?

Comment: It's important to note that many initiatives could benefit African-Americans, their communities, and their community (if they could be said to have a unified community, which is perhaps debatable) without being specifically directed at them.  An example would be social safety net programs, because they benefit poor people, and while there is proportionally more poverty among the black population than among the non-hispanic white population, there are more non-hispanic white beneficiaries of these programs in absolute terms. Would a promise to enhance these programs count for this question?

Answer (score 11):

The [2020 Democratic Party Platform](https://www.demconvention.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/2020-07-31-Democratic-Party-Platform-For-Distribution.pdf), adopted at the DNC and on which Biden & Harris stood, covers a lot of their policies on this subject. Just to pick out a few:

- Grants for Historically Black Colleges & Universities (pg. 10)
- Expanded funding for Community Development Financial Institutions (pg. 11)
- A promise to increase the authority & funding-level of the Equal Employment Opportunity Commission (pg. 15)
- A promise to 'vigorously enforce' various housing legislation, including the Fair Housing Act & the Affirmatively Furthering Fair Housing rule (pg. 22)
- Expand postpartum Medicaid coverage to a year after birth to attempt to tackle the racial gap in maternal mortality (pg. 33)
- End the 'War on Drugs', which "has imprisoned millions of
  Americans—disproportionately Black people and Latinos—and hasn’t been effective in reducing
  drug use" (pg. 36)
- "Invest in recovering, celebrating, and highlighting Black history as American history" & make June 19th ([Juneteenth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneteenth)) a federal holiday. (pg. 40)
- Attempt to address inequalities in the Armed Forces by "[accelerating] efforts to recruit and promote
  people of color in the officer corps" (pg. 77)

Comment: This is I think the relevant page from the Campaign's website; https://joebiden.com/blackamerica/ which has a lot of additional reading for anyone who wants it.

Comment: It bears mention that many of these points are not specifically directed toward African-American communities.